# Javascript to change the backgorund color of an Inputbox based on a condition

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to change the Inputbox color when a certain condition meets. For example, I have an Inputbox called "numberfield-inputF1" when the inputbox's border is red, then I want the inputbox's background filled with red.

I have this code below but doesn't work.

```
var inputfield = document.getElementsByClassName("x-form-field x-form-required-field x-form-text x-form-invalid-field empty-field-cls")  
   // inputfield.style.backgroundColor = '#c30';
  if (inputfield.style.borderColor == '#c30')  
  {
    inputfield.style.backgroundColor == '#c30';
  } else {
inputfield.style.backgroundColor == '#FFF';
  }
```

This is the HTML Source code.

```
<td id="numberfield-inputF1" class="x-form-trigger-input-cell" style="width: 100%;"><input id="numberfield-inputF1" type="text" size="1" name="numberfield-inputF1" placeholder="800 - 2200" class="x-form-field x-form-required-field x-form-text x-form-invalid-field empty-field-cls" autocomplete="off" aria-invalid="true" data-errorqtip="<ul class=&quot;x-list-plain&quot;><li role=&quot;alert&quot;>This field is required</li></ul>" style="width: 100%;"></td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note:** `getElementsByClassName` method returns an array of matching elements rather than giving an object of a single matching element. Correct code way to handle this would be:

```js
var inputfields = document.getElementsByClassName("x-form-field x-form-required-field x-form-text x-form-invalid-field empty-field-cls");

for (const inputfield of inputfields) {
  if (inputfield.style.borderColor == '#c30') {
    inputfield.style.backgroundColor = '#c30';
  } else {
    inputfield.style.backgroundColor = '#FFF';
  }
}
```

```html
<td id="numberfield-inputF1" class="x-form-trigger-input-cell" style="width: 100%;">
  <input id="numberfield-inputF1" type="text" size="1" name="numberfield-inputF1" placeholder="800 - 2200" class="x-form-field x-form-required-field x-form-text x-form-invalid-field empty-field-cls" autocomplete="off" aria-invalid="true" data-errorqtip="<ul class=&quot;x-list-plain&quot;><li role=&quot;alert&quot;>This field is required</li></ul>"
    style="width: 100%;">
</td>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. How do I make it work when the event triggers. like, usually, the inputbox border is white but when I enter the wrong data, the input box becomes red. So, I want the Javascript to make the inputbox background to red.

Comment: You can handle it with [oninvalid](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_oninvalid.asp) event. You can bind the event to the input like shown in the link and then use the logic in my answer to change the background color @cmk

Comment: Let me know if you need me to provide an example in my answer to change color on invalid event. @cmk

Answer (score 0):

Notice that `getElementsByClassName` give you more than one so get the first founded with `getElementsByClassName(someName)[0]`.

```js
var inputfield = document.getElementsByClassName("x-form-field x-form-required-field x-form-text x-form-invalid-field empty-field-cls")[0];
  inputfield.style.backgroundColor = '#c30';
  if (inputfield.style.borderColor == '#c30'){
    inputfield.style.backgroundColor == '#c30';
  }
  else{
    inputfield.style.backgroundColor == '#FFF';
  }
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <td id="numberfield-inputF1" class="x-form-trigger-input-cell" style="width: 100%;">
      <input id="numberfield-inputF1" type="text" size="1" name="numberfield-inputF1" placeholder="800 - 2200" class="x-form-field x-form-required-field x-form-text x-form-invalid-field empty-field-cls" autocomplete="off" aria-invalid="true" data-errorqtip="<ul class=&quot;x-list-plain&quot;><li role=&quot;alert&quot;>This field is required</li></ul>" style="width: 100%;"/>
    </td>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. How do I make it work when the event triggers. like, usually, the inputbox border is white but when I enter the wrong data, the input box becomes red. So, I want the Javascript to make the inputbox background to red

Comment: Add the ```onchange="some javascript"``` attribute to your input element but you don't need to ask anything here. A great website for beginners: [link](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You are seriously overworking this - it does not - NOT need js - you already have the classes on the input- simply use CSS to color the background when its invalid - as already indicated by the classname.

With the invalid class ('x-form-invalid-field') - you can color the border and the background together.

```css
label {
display: block;
}

.x-form-field {
    border: solid 1px #6e6e6e;
    background: #fff;
    height: 32px; 
    width: 100px;
    color: #6e6e6e
}
  
  .x-form-field.x-form-invalid-field {
    border-color: #c30;
    background: #c30;
    color: #fff;

}
```

```html
  <label> input without error</label>
  <input class="x-form-field x-form-required-field x-form-tex empty-field-cls" type="text" value="valid content"/>

 <hr/>

  <label> input with error</label>
  <input class="x-form-field x-form-required-field x-form-text x-form-invalid-field empty-field-cls" type="text" value="invalid content"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try with this code

html

```
<td id="numberfield-inputF1" class="x-form-trigger-input-cell" style="width: 100%;">
    <input id="numberfield-inputF1" type="text" size="1" name="numberfield-inputF1" placeholder="800 - 2200"
        class="x-form-field x-form-required-field x-form-text x-form-invalid-field empty-field-cls" autocomplete="off"
        aria-invalid="true"
        data-errorqtip="<ul class=&quot;x-list-plain&quot;><li role=&quot;alert&quot;>This field is required</li></ul>"
        style="width: 100%; border-color:red">
</td>
```

js:

```
window.onload = function () {
        var my_input = document.getElementById("numberfield-inputF1");
        document.getElementById("numberfield-inputF1").onmouseover = function () {

            if (my_input.style.borderColor === 'red') {
                my_input.style.backgroundColor = 'green';

            } else {
                my_input.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';

            }
        }
        document.getElementById("numberfield-inputF1").onmouseout = function () {
            my_input.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow, here are some guidelines : **it is not recommended** to post code-only answers, answers should provide more explanation about the code to make it the answer more useful and are more likely to attract upvotes